# Multiple apps, one database. how to do cross session for users?

Tags: php, symfony, session, cross-domain

I have two Symfony applications. They point on the same database for sharing some tables.
So one user can login into app1 and app2 with the same username and password. But the session is blocked for the app is logged in. I'm using FosUserBundle.

My question is, how to share the session to the differents apps ?

I tried to add in the config.yml this line on the two apps :

```
framwork:
  session:
    cookie_domain: .my-domain.com
    name: SFSESSID
```

Indeed app1 is available on app1.my-domain.com and app2 is available on app2.my-domain.com

Second possible answer is to listen login event and perform login when i view session of my second app. Right ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it won't work in this way, because user will have your cookie only on one of domains. You can create an API to share information about that if user is logged in and recognize who he is, but the right way to do this is creating third application - Single Sign On which will be purposed only, and only to login and authorize user. Your two current apps will always authorize and authenticate user with SSO.

To implement this you can use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/ as a server and https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle as Clients.

Or, if you want to do this really quickly but messy you can create a JS script which will call the second page and create own cookie there. But if somebody asked you I haven't recommended you that.

Piotr

Comment: I understand, but on this website they explain how to do session available on cross sub-domain. Its not a good solution ? http://www.elao.com/blog/symfony-2/subdomains-symfony2-2-session-authentication.html